# Cordova uploadfile function returns code: 200 and the whole php page source code

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I am using cordova file transfer plugin to upload files from cordova app to a server. My server works without problem and i can upload files from my browser.

However, when it comes to upload them from mu cordova app, I get return code 200 and the whole upload php page code. And the files does not become uploaded.

The server and app are connected, when i click upload button, a tmp file is made in the server and suddenly deleted. When i change the put a wrong adress in upload functions i receive error code 3.

```
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var directory = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "PATH TO FILE";
var ft = new FileTransfer();
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {
      Connection: "close"
   };


var win = function(result){console.log("Code = " + result.responseCode); console.log(result.response);};
var fail = function(event){console.log(event); };


button1.onclick = function(){
ft.upload(directory, encodeURI("MYDOMAIN.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @SLaks code is now added.

Comment: Your URL is probably wrong; you need a relative path or a protocol.  And `encodeURI` is only for encoding data assembled into a URL.

Comment: @SLaks https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html    It is done just like i did in the documentation. What do you mean by relative path or protocol?